# iPhone makes a random sound (not a notification sound)

Tags: iphone, ios

Starting about a couple months ago, my iPhone 11 started to make a random sound:

- I Googled this question, but the answers are all about finding the app notification setting where no banners or badges but a sound is enabled. I tried but no such setting on my iPhone.
- The random sound is actually not a notification sound at all. It sounds like Do-Mi-So.
- I have went through all sound settings in my iPhone, none sounds like this random sound Do-Mi-So. I also went through a lot of sound iPhone could make from YouTube videos, I can't identify the sound.
- The random sound happens 3-4 times a day. Sometimes, it doesn’t happen for several days.
- I have no app running (no apps in the app switcher), the random sound still occurs. I am a very light app user btw.
- With silent mode on, the random sound still occurs.
- With Do Not Disturb on, the random sound still occurs.
- My iOS has been updated to iOS 16.2, and the random sound is still there.

Comment: Could it be the [Find My alert](https://youtu.be/Cn5bKRU6PMg)?

Comment: @Allan No, it's not. The random sound just do-mi-so, that's it, no repetition.

Comment: If you’re on silent mode, then you won’t hear notifications, so, it’s down to an App.  Since it’s highly unlikely  you have no apps at all open, the next time it happens, open the app switcher and see what’s running. Then you can start narrowing it down.

Comment: Is it possible that some app (or malware) is dialing a phone number that is disconnected?  "do-mi-so" sounds a bit like the tones that precede the announcement that the number is disconnected.  OR, do you have an anti-autodialer app like Robokiller installed?  At least one app of that type uses those tones to fool autodialers into promptly disconnecting.

Comment: I hear this on occasion as well and I cannot figure it out. It mostly happens when I’m holding my phone with one hand, and am moving that hand (i.e. reaching for a pillow, grabbing the blanket, etc.)

Comment: Do you have automatic updates on anything?  I haven't heard it recently, but if I recall correctly, when a download completes, I get three tones, each higher pitch than the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I had/have similar situation. Except the sounds I hear sound like a series of Morse code sounds, l I talk to a federal communications engineer and he thought this was likely due to radio towers broadcasting a burst of signals at a certain frequency that they should not be broadcasting.
Also I noticed this with only occur when my phone was very near or next to a speaker, whether, or not, the speaker/device was on.
Really weird.